# Mapping show to a list of a custom data type

Tags: haskell

As part of a large project at university to write an interpreter in Haskell for a simple custom language, I am trying to print some things to help me in my quest to write this thing.

There's a custom data type

```
data Prog = Prog [Func]
    deriving (Show, Read)
```

and when I try to print an instance of this prog in the last line of this function

```
interpret :: Prog -> Vars -> String -> MaybeDebug -> IO ()
interpret prog vars entry _ = do
    putStrLn "The interpreter isn't written yet.  Better get onto that!"
    putStrLn "\n\n"
    putStrLn (show prog)
    putStrLn "\n\n"
    putStrLn (show vars)
    putStrLn "\n\n"
    putStrLn (show entry)
    putStrLn "\n\n"
    putStrLn (map show [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry])
```

I receive an error "Couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type 'String'.

I have been trying for some time to work out what the problem is here. Why is it mentioning chars when this list comprehension returns a list of funcs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
map show [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry]
```

produces a list of `String`s, but `putStrLn` takes a single `String`, or `[Char]`, as argument.

So the expected type of the list elements is `Char`, but the actual type is `String`.

Depending on what output you desire, the last line should be something like

```
putStrLn (unlines $ map show [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry])
```

or

```
mapM_ putStrLn (map show [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry])
```

(that would be better

```
mapM_ print [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry]
```

however).

Then, in the list comprehension, when you write `func <- prog`, `prog` must be a list, but the argument to `interpret` is a `Prog`, a list wrapped in a constructor `Prog`. You need to unwrap the list to use it in the list comprehension, for example

```
interpret prog@(Prog functions) vars entry _ = do
```

with an as-pattern, and then

```
func <- functions
```

in the list comprehension.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes perfect sense. However, now Haskell complains that it can't match expected type '[t0]' with actual type 'Prog'. This is a problem I thought I had fixed by introducing map show, but it seems as though it has just masked it. Do you happen to have an equally surprisingly simple explanation for this quandary as well?

Comment: Updated with a possible fix for that.

Comment: Hey dude thanks so much. Your explanations are really clear, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Daniel, the problem is that putStrLn expects a String, not a list of Strings.

I suggest intercalate to print a comma separated list.

```
putStrLn (intercalate ", " (map show [func | func <- prog, (func_name func) == entry]))
```

You need to import Data.List to get the intercalate function.